# Series expansions of inverse polynomials

Tags: polynomials, power-series, inverse

Suppose one is given a strictly monotonous polynomial,
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$$

So that for a given $y$ there exists a single real $x=f^{-1}(y)$. It would be nice* to be able to calculate the inverse value directly using a power series, i.e.:

$$x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n y^n$$

Is there a method of calculating the coefficients for the power series for arbitrary $N$? how about for $N<5$?
$$$$

<sub>*I'm aware of course that for practical applications iterative methods are the way to go, but this seems like more fun.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [Series Reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

The analytical expression for the inverse coefficients can be written out, but it gets quite complex for higher $n$.